# minimum C rate of battery cells

Tags: lithium-ion

What is the minimum C rating for li-ion battery cells? I am trying to charge 3.7V 10Ah battery pack with small 0.3W solar cell. I used LTC3105 DC/DC boost converter to boost voltage of solar cell to 4.2V. I could not find any online documentation or thread for this. I know it is safe to charge with lower C rating. My question is will my battery even gets charged with such small current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming perfect charge efficiency, that battery needs to be supplied \$3.7V \times 10A \times 3600s = 133.2kJ\$ to charge.

At the maximum solar cell output of 0.3W and assuming all of it goes to the battery, it would take \$\frac{133.2kJ}{0.3W}=444,000 seconds = 123 hours\$

to supply that. Since that faster than it takes for the battery to self-discharge, yes it will charge. You might not want to wait around though.

Comment: thank you. It is an IoT device. I think I can trust this setup so that it can charge fully in summer and discharges in winter. current drain is very low. it sleeps for 59 minutes with a current draw of around 0.6mA and on for 1 minute with 40mA

Comment: 0.6mA is a lot for sleeping, there is likely optimization potential there.

Comment: yes, we are working on that. thank you